# Make AJAX continue working and update its status on UI even if user redirects or navigates to another page

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, api, flask

I'm using Flask and JQuery to try to achieve this but pls feel free to suggest any other stack(React/Angular) if that's super easy.

I have the below AJAX in a poll.js file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#poll').click(function(){
        
        $('#poll').text("Working...")
        
        $.ajax({
            
            url: '/poll',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
                $('#poll').text("Poll")
            },
            error: function(error){
                console.log(error);
                $('#poll').text("Poll")
            }
        });

        
    });

    
});
```

and my poll function in app.py is as below:

```
@app.route('/poll', methods=['GET'])
def poll():
     call an api and return the json response
```

now on the UI if i click the poll button its text changes to working and it calls the function which eventually hits the API.

While this is happening, if click the home menu or navigate elsewhere on the page, i loose the AJAX call.

How do i make the ajax call continue working i.e. calling the api and updating the UI even if we try to redirect to another page or click anywhere else?

Comment: Any action (click) that will navigate away from the current page will abandon the request, think of better approach.

Comment: Yes @ZubairAhmd, expecting help here to suggest a better approach.

Comment: Normally in such cases data is loaded on initial page load and if need periodically updated setInterval is pretty useful.

- Suggestion is make a call on page load each time a visitor comes to page
- make use of setInterval to get periodical updates

Comment: I'm unable to make it work. Trying to do the same with using React :(

Comment: I can provide with jQuery code, don't know how to do in React but I think it should give you hint ?

Comment: Yes pls @ZubairAhmd!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to load the data on initial page load and then refresh after set interval. to achieve this following should give you a kick start

```
<script type="application/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    
    /* change this 
    $('#poll').click(function(){
    
        $('#poll').text("Working...")
        
        $.ajax({
        
        url: '/poll',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
            $('#poll').text("Poll")
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log(error);
            $('#poll').text("Poll")
        }
        });
    });
    */
    //to this it will start with page load and refresh $('#poll') every 5 seconds
    var setInt = setInterval($(function(){
                $('#poll').text("Working...")
                $.ajax({
                    url:'path to script',
                    data: $('#form').serialize(), //your html must have form with id="form" for this
                    type: 'GET',
                    success: function(response){
                        console.log(response);
                        $('#poll').text("Poll")
                    },
                }).fail(function(xhr,ajaxOptin,thrownError){
                    //console.error(xhr.responseText);
                    console.error(thrownError);
                });
            }), 5000);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Apologies but this doesn’t help. :(